# SendMessage - sending case-sensitive keys

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I'm trying to make a working function to write given text key by key in other application, for example a notepad, using WinAPI `SendMessage` function. I have a code like this:

```
//
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, 0x41, 0);
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)Keys.A, 0); // 0x41
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)'A', 0); // 0x41
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)'a', 0); // 0x61
//

SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)Keys.Space, 0);

//
SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.Shift, 0);

SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, 0x41, 0);
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)Keys.A, 0); // 0x41
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)'A', 0); // 0x41
SendMessage(handle, WM_CHAR, (int)'a', 0); // 0x61

SendMessage(handle, WM_KEYUP, (int)Keys.Shift, 0);
//
```

which is supposed to write output like:

```
aaa1 AAA1
```

but this code wrote:

```
AAAa AAAa
```

Why does this happen? `0x41` is Virtual-Key code for <kbd>A</kbd> key, without <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed it should create lower-case letter `a`, and [char `a` = `0x61`] whould really not put lowercase 'a' on output, but 1 on Numpad (
`VK_NUMPAD1 0x61` Numeric keypad `1` key) as on this site:

[Virtual-Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Anyone has any idea how to send lower- and upper-case letters via `SendMessage` to other applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the way it works.  The normal way is that the user presses the A key on the keyboard.  That generates a WM_KEYDOWN message for Notepad.  Notepad receives this message when it called GetMessage().  It then calls TranslateMessage() and *that* generates a WM_CHAR message.  The generated character depends on the keyboard state (like the Shift key) and the user's selected keyboard layout.  Both keyboard state and layout are process specific.

So what you did by sending WM_CHAR was doing all the work that Notepad itself normally does.  Which is fine, you do **not** want to post WM_KEYDOWN messages.  Because you cannot predict what character that's going to generate.  You cannot find out what Notepad's keyboard state and active layout are.

Simply send (WPARAM)'A' if you want an uppercase A, (WPARAM)'a' if you want a lowercase a.

Comment: So simple yet correct. You should've seen my painfull way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer is that WM_CHAR handles text and isn't really designed to handle virtual keys. It also processes whatever character you send it. WM_KEYDOWN, however, does handle virtual keys