# C# Auto typing in a selected process

Tags: c#, process

So hey guys im trying to create an auto typer wich for example only auto types in Internet Explorer

This script

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("JLauncher");

foreach (Process proc in processes)
    PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, detail, 0);

int detail = 0x33
```

Basically this script presses 3 on the keyboard only in the process `JLauncher`

I was wondering if there's a way to combine this script with:

```
SendKeys.Send();
```

So basically:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("JLauncher");

foreach (Process proc in processes)
    PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, SendKeys.Send("Hello"), 0);
```

I understand that this forum isnt for you guys to code stuff for others, but i really need a line of script for this

Could anny1 help please?

Comment: Soo basicly like

 Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("JLauncher");

        foreach (Process proc in processes)
SendKeys.Send(proc.MainWindowHandle, "Hello")

Comment: In Sweden, we say "det dunkelt sagda är det dunkelt tänkta". Not sure if it would survive translation.

Comment: yes that translates just fine to unclearly said unclearly thought :)

Comment: I want a code wich puts a SendKeys only in a selected process JLauncher how unclear is that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send multiple [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx) events to type a string. To do that you first have to parse the string into the corresponding `wParam` values (which are [virtual key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx)) for `PostMessage`. You can use [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey(v=vs.110).aspx) to get those.

To get you started, a simplified version (doesn't handle lower/upper case characters) could look like this:

```
private static void SendKeysTo(Process proc, string str)
{
    foreach (var ch in str)
    {
        Key result;
        if (Enum.TryParse(ch + "", true, out result))
        {
            PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(result), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

You should also consider sending [WM_CHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx) [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182263/sendmessage-sending-case-sensitive-keys)